# Can't open Miranda programming language tar ball Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, tar, miranda

I'm trying to:

```
sudo tar xpzf mira-2044-x86_64-Darwin.tgz -C /
```

I am in the correct directory (my Downloads folder) but I get this error:

> ./usr/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usrCan't update time for usr
>   tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

What does this error mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Option `p` of `tar` means preserve permissions.

`tar` is attempting to set file permission, ownership and modification time of some existing directories. In MacOS, `/usr` is owned by `root:wheel` but the archive has it owned by `root:root`.

Unfortunately, when running `tar` as superuser, the default is to preserve permissions. So you cannot turn this off.

Fortunately, `k` option of `tar` will skip overwriting existing files or directories. You can tell `tar` not to overwrite `/usr`, `/usr/local`, `/usr/local/bin` and any directories that you already have.

Modification time is always restored when a file or directory is restored. Option `k` will already prevent modification time to get updated when it tells `tar` not to overwrite existing directories/files. It is still better to know that the option `m` tells `tar` not to update the modification time of a file/directory.

You should now be able to install `miranda` by running:

```
sudo tar xmpkvzf mira-2044-x86_64-Darwin.tgz -C /
```

That added `v` (verbose) option is just to let you see what are being extracted.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell which flag is responsible for  the `Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr` part and which one for the `Can't update time for usr`? I suppose I will need to post a second question regarding why the flags `-fvxz` failed with one  compressed package image (not for miranda)  and succeed with another image of that package just a couple of minor versions later. Not a concern on the bounty. I've got lots of rep to burn. If no one give a more expansive answer it will be yours.

Comment: @42- Updated my answer for you.